# De Morgan Law in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

According to De Morgan law:

```
¬(P ˄ Q) ↔ (¬P) ˅ (¬Q)
¬(P ˅ Q) ↔ (¬P) ˄ (¬Q)
```

In Python 3.5 when I run:

```
A = True
B = True
x = not(A and B)==(not A) or (not B)
y = not(A or B)==(not A) and (not B)
print('x is :', x, '\ny is :' ,y)
```

This returns:

```
x is : True 
y is : False
```

Question: why y is False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding some parentheses -- `==` is higher precedence than `or`.

Here is the [precedence table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
y = not(A or B)==((not A) and (not B))
```

It was evaluating

```
not(A or B) == (not A)
```

first.

Answer (score 0):

Operator priority is tripping you up. In Python, the `==` operator has higher priority than `not`. The expression `not a == b` is read as `not (a == b)` rather than `(not a) == b`, because the former is usually more useful than the latter.

Therefore, your `y` should look like:

```
y = (not(A or B)) == ((not A) and (not B))
```

And your `x` should look like:

```
x = (not(A and B)) == ((not A) or (not B))
```

Then you'll get the right results. (Your `x` is also wrong, and is getting a `True` result for the wrong reasons: it's actually evaluating `(not ((A and B) == (not A)) or (not B)` which works out to `(not (True == False)) or False` which works out to `True or False`. But what you **actually** wanted was `(not (A and B)) == ((not A) or (not B))`, which works out to `(not True) == (False or False)`, which works out to `False == False`. As I said, your `x` is getting a `True` result for the wrong reasons.)